# Native camera parameters on HTC Desire

Tags: android, parameters, camera

I am developing a camera application on a HTC Desire and wonder about some of the native Camera.Parameter settings. Hopefully someone over here has more insights.

When calling unflatten() on the obtained Camera.Parameters object, I get a long list with key-value pairs. Some of them are the following:

```
sharpness-def=10;
sharpness-max=30;
sharpness-min=0;
sharpness=10;

contrast-min=0;
contrast-max=10;
contrast-def=5;
contrast=5;

brightness-min=0;
brightness-max=6;
brightness-def=3;
brightness=3;

saturation-min=1;
saturation-max=10;
saturation=5;
saturation-def=5;

enable-caf=off;

vertical-view-angle=42.5;
horizontal-view-angle=54.8;
```

There are min/max boundaries for sharpness, contrast, brightness and saturation. But I am not sure about the difference between e.g. brightness and brightness-def. It is actually possible to set both with the API call set(String key, String value). Which one holds the actual value and what is the other one for?

What might be "enable-caf" for?

And for vertical-view-angle and horizontal-view-angle I always get the same values - maybe static values for lens correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable-caf...

This is continuous auto focus. Ie should the camera keep trying to refocus.

Am trying to do something relating to this, will post back if I make any progress...

BTW not all phones support CAF apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the def parameters stands for **default**.
You need to have a steady reference to go back to when it comes to playing with camera parameters.

As for the camera-caf value... wow. No idea. Have you tried turning it on?

BR
Ita